# I dont find the solution

Tags: sql

I am trying to execute the following SQL query but it is not working:

```
update fichas1
set 
fichas1.observaciones = concat(casi.diagnostico+ ' '+ casi.localizacion +'\n' +casi.tecnica )
from fichas1 inner join casi on fichas1.id = casi.ficha_id
```

Comment: and the error message is.....

Comment: @user852610 - please add additional details like what the error message is, why the update didn't occur, expected results, actual results, etc. It will help us help you.

Comment: LittleBobbyTables - How about understanding that not everyone speaks english who is on the site, snarky comments aside and ask the user for additional details nicely...

Comment: Well, without knowing the error message, I'm guessing that your syntax for concat is wrong.  Generally it's either concat('Item1','Item2','Item3') or just 'Item1' + 'Item2' + 'Item3' rather than concat('Item1' + 'Item2' + 'Item3').

Comment: In standard SQL, the concatenation operator is `||`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
update fichas1
set 
fichas1.observaciones = (select concat(casi.diagnostico+ ' '+ casi.localizacion +'\n' +casi.tecnica)
from casi where fichas1.id = casi.ficha_id)
```

It may fail on multiple result set for the select query though.

Comment: You might want to add the WHERE clause in the outer update routine or you will update the entire table.

Comment: @JonH Good point, but I assume that OP wants to update all records after adding new field to the table.

Comment: could be, the comment was a warning to the OP.